# Injected values in Quartz Job are null in play framework 2.5

Tags: java, dependency-injection, quartz-scheduler, playframework-2.5

Here I have a sample using Quartz scheduling

```
public class SampleJob implements Job {

    @Inject
    private MyClass sample;

    @Override
    public void execute( JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext ) throws JobExecutionException {
        sample.runSampleWithDBConnection();

    }
}

public class SampleScheduling {

    private String cronExpression = ;

    public void run() throws SchedulerException {

        Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();

        JobDetail job = newJob(SampleJob.class).withIdentity("job1", "group1").build();

        CronTrigger trigger = newTrigger().withIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
                                          .withSchedule(cronSchedule("0 5 * * * ? *"))
                                          .build();

        Date nextRuntime = scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
        scheduler.start();

    }
}
```

In the above sample when the Quartz triggers the Job Its getting null for the injected MyClass. where MyClass is simple java class with a method

```
public class MyClass {
    @Inject
    @NamedDatabase("default")
    private Database defaultDb;
    public void runSampleWithDBConnection() {
        defaultDb.getConnection();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to assign not null value for sample. Now in the SampleJob class the sample variable is null.

Comment: @KrishanthyMohanachandran how can we assign not null value. In DI usually objects were injected with `@Inject`

Comment: please clean and build the project and check

Comment: I found the solution to the problem

Comment: What was the solution? @Niamath